# Force radiobutton to select only one value

Tags: android, android-listview, radio-button

I am using a radiobutton in LayoutInflater, Currently it is selecting all values in a view, i want to select only one out of all in listview, how can i do that ?

Working code :

MainActivity.java

```
package com.androidhub4you.multilevellistview;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.androidhub4you.multilevellistview.Product.SubCategory;
import com.androidhub4you.multilevellistview.Product.SubCategory.ItemList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
/**
 * 
 * @author manish
 *
 */
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ArrayList<Product>pProductArrayList;
    private ArrayList<SubCategory>pSubItemArrayList;
    private ArrayList<SubCategory>pSubItemArrayList2;
    private LinearLayout mLinearListView;
    boolean isFirstViewClick=false;
    boolean isSecondViewClick=false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mLinearListView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_listview);

        /**
         * 
         */

        ArrayList<ItemList> mItemListArray=new ArrayList<ItemList>();
        mItemListArray.add(new ItemList("Red", "20"));
        mItemListArray.add(new ItemList("Blue", "50"));
        mItemListArray.add(new ItemList("Red", "20"));
        mItemListArray.add(new ItemList("Blue", "50"));

        ArrayList<ItemList> mItemListArray2=new ArrayList<ItemList>();
        mItemListArray2.add(new ItemList("Pant", "2000"));
        mItemListArray2.add(new ItemList("Shirt", "1000"));
        mItemListArray2.add(new ItemList("Pant", "2000"));
        mItemListArray2.add(new ItemList("Shirt", "1000"));
        mItemListArray2.add(new ItemList("Pant", "2000"));
        mItemListArray2.add(new ItemList("Shirt", "1000"));


        /**
         * 
         */
        pSubItemArrayList=new ArrayList<SubCategory>();
        pSubItemArrayList2=new ArrayList<SubCategory>();
        pSubItemArrayList.add(new SubCategory("Color", mItemListArray));
        pSubItemArrayList2.add(new SubCategory("Cloths", mItemListArray2));
        pSubItemArrayList.add(new SubCategory("Color", mItemListArray));
        pSubItemArrayList2.add(new SubCategory("Cloths", mItemListArray2));
        /**
         * 
         */

        pProductArrayList=new ArrayList<Product>();
        pProductArrayList.add(new Product("Emotions", pSubItemArrayList));
        pProductArrayList.add(new Product("Garments", pSubItemArrayList2));


        /***
         * adding item into listview
         */
        for (int i = 0; i < pProductArrayList.size(); i++) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = null;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View mLinearView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_first, null);

            final TextView mProductName = (TextView) mLinearView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
            final RelativeLayout mLinearFirstArrow=(RelativeLayout)mLinearView.findViewById(R.id.linearFirst);
            final ImageView mImageArrowFirst=(ImageView)mLinearView.findViewById(R.id.imageFirstArrow);
            final LinearLayout mLinearScrollSecond=(LinearLayout)mLinearView.findViewById(R.id.linear_scroll);

            if(isFirstViewClick==false){
            mLinearScrollSecond.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mImageArrowFirst.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arw_lt);
            }
            else{
                mLinearScrollSecond.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mImageArrowFirst.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arw_down);
            }

            mLinearFirstArrow.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                    if(isFirstViewClick==false){
                        isFirstViewClick=true;
                        mImageArrowFirst.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arw_down);
                        mLinearScrollSecond.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }else{
                        isFirstViewClick=false;
                        mImageArrowFirst.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arw_lt);
                        mLinearScrollSecond.setVisibility(View.GONE);   
                    }
                    return false;
                } 
            });


            final String name = pProductArrayList.get(i).getpName();
            mProductName.setText(name);

            /**
             * 
             */
            for (int j = 0; j < pProductArrayList.get(i).getmSubCategoryList().size(); j++) {

                LayoutInflater inflater2 = null;
                inflater2 = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View mLinearView2 = inflater2.inflate(R.layout.row_second, null);

                TextView mSubItemName = (TextView) mLinearView2.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
                final RelativeLayout mLinearSecondArrow=(RelativeLayout)mLinearView2.findViewById(R.id.linearSecond);
                final ImageView mImageArrowSecond=(ImageView)mLinearView2.findViewById(R.id.imageSecondArrow);
                final LinearLayout mLinearScrollThird=(LinearLayout)mLinearView2.findViewById(R.id.linear_scroll_third);

                if(isSecondViewClick==false){
                    mLinearScrollThird.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mImageArrowSecond.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arw_lt);
                    }
                    else{
                        mLinearScrollThird.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mImageArrowSecond.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arw_down);
                    }

                mLinearSecondArrow.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                        @Override
                        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                            if(isSecondViewClick==false){
                                isSecondViewClick=true;
                                mImageArrowSecond.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arw_down);
                                mLinearScrollThird.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            }else{
                                isSecondViewClick=false;
                                mImageArrowSecond.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arw_lt);
                                mLinearScrollThird.setVisibility(View.GONE);    
                            }
                            return false;
                        } 
                    });


                final String catName = pProductArrayList.get(i).getmSubCategoryList().get(j).getpSubCatName();
                mSubItemName.setText(catName);
                /**
                 * 
                 */
                  for (int k = 0; k < pProductArrayList.get(i).getmSubCategoryList().get(j).getmItemListArray().size(); k++) {

                        LayoutInflater inflater3 = null;
                        inflater3 = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        View mLinearView3 = inflater3.inflate(R.layout.row_third, null);

                        TextView mItemName = (TextView) mLinearView3.findViewById(R.id.textViewItemName);
                        TextView mItemPrice = (TextView) mLinearView3.findViewById(R.id.textViewItemPrice);
                        final String itemName = pProductArrayList.get(i).getmSubCategoryList().get(j).getmItemListArray().get(k).getItemName();
                        final String itemPrice = pProductArrayList.get(i).getmSubCategoryList().get(j).getmItemListArray().get(k).getItemPrice();
                        mItemName.setText(itemName);
                        mItemPrice.setText(itemPrice);

                        mLinearScrollThird.addView(mLinearView3);
                  }

                mLinearScrollSecond.addView(mLinearView2);

            }

            mLinearListView.addView(mLinearView);
        }       
    }

}
```

Product.java

```
package com.androidhub4you.multilevellistview;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * 
 * first level item
 * 
 */
public class Product {

    private String pName;

    private ArrayList<SubCategory> mSubCategoryList;

    public Product(String pName, ArrayList<SubCategory> mSubCategoryList) {
        super();
        this.pName = pName;
        this.mSubCategoryList = mSubCategoryList;
    }

    public String getpName() {
        return pName;
    }

    public void setpName(String pName) {
        this.pName = pName;
    }

    public ArrayList<SubCategory> getmSubCategoryList() {
        return mSubCategoryList;
    }

    public void setmSubCategoryList(ArrayList<SubCategory> mSubCategoryList) {
        this.mSubCategoryList = mSubCategoryList;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * second level item
     * 
     */

    public static class SubCategory {

        private String pSubCatName;
        private ArrayList<ItemList> mItemListArray;

        public SubCategory(String pSubCatName,
                ArrayList<ItemList> mItemListArray) {
            super();
            this.pSubCatName = pSubCatName;
            this.mItemListArray = mItemListArray;
        }

        public String getpSubCatName() {
            return pSubCatName;
        }

        public void setpSubCatName(String pSubCatName) {
            this.pSubCatName = pSubCatName;
        }

        public ArrayList<ItemList> getmItemListArray() {
            return mItemListArray;
        }

        public void setmItemListArray(ArrayList<ItemList> mItemListArray) {
            this.mItemListArray = mItemListArray;
        }

        /**
         * 
         * third level item
         * 
         */
        public static class ItemList {

            private String itemName;
            private String itemPrice;

            public ItemList(String itemName, String itemPrice) {
                super();
                this.itemName = itemName;
                this.itemPrice = itemPrice;
            }

            public String getItemName() {
                return itemName;
            }

            public void setItemName(String itemName) {
                this.itemName = itemName;
            }

            public String getItemPrice() {
                return itemPrice;
            }

            public void setItemPrice(String itemPrice) {
                this.itemPrice = itemPrice;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

</ScrollView>
```

row_third.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewItemName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewItemPrice"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

  <RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/selection"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4px"
    android:layout_marginRight="10px"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    />


        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Add your radioButtons in a radioGroup

Comment: yes, that is correct! Radio Group is the solution.

Comment: @WISHY : But, its only one radiobutton i am iterating, i don't want to hardcode radiobuttons in radiogroup

Comment: @Christine in that case use radioButton.setChecked(false);

Comment: Let me add my code, I have a radiobutton in a Layoutinflater. Current implementation selects all radio buttons in a list, I want only one radio button to be selected at a time. How can I do that?

Comment: Yeah I understood your question. Yet the the solution for it is quite tricky and complex. You need to create an array with size of number of radiobuttons presents and also an array of the radiobuttons and fill them with default value of boolean false. Now when the user selects any of the radio button you update the value in the array. Since the user has selected you can disable all the radiButtons using radioBut.setEnabled(false); User won't be able to select any of the radiobuttons thn

Comment: @WISHY : Ok, how bout if i hardcode the radiobuttons in radiogroup? Would that be good option ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77485/discussion-between-wishy-and-christine).

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_pirates"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/pirates"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_ninjas"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ninjas"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
</RadioGroup>
```

On radio button click

```
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    // Is the button now checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.radio_pirates:
            if (checked)
                // Pirates are the best
            break;
        case R.id.radio_ninjas:
            if (checked)
                // Ninjas rule
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: But i am not hardcoding my radiobuttons, it is dynamic

Comment: Why don't you using CustomArraryAdapter using BaseAdapter for your listview  follow this http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/  you will get a idea

Answer (score 0):

You can check programatically if any radioButton is checked, and uncheck it before checking the selected one using `radiobutton1.isChecked()` in a for loop.

Answer (score -1):

Put the `RadioButton` controls inside of a [`RadioGroup`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html).

As the linked documentation states, a `RadioGroup` handles this automatically:

> This class is used to create a multiple-exclusion scope for a set of radio buttons. Checking one radio button that belongs to a radio group unchecks any previously checked radio button within the same group.